# Loading Jqgrid in asp.net not functioning as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I am facing problem in loading jqgrid.

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
          url: 'Default.aspx/getData?2',
          datatype: "json",
          colNames: ['Dosage', 'Drug', 'Patient', 'Date'],
          colModel: [
          { name: 'Dosage', index: 'Dosage', width: 20},
          { name: 'Drug', index: 'Drug', width: 150, stype: 'text'},
          { name: 'Patient', index: 'Patient', width: 150},
          { name: 'Date', index: 'Date', width: 60}
          ],
          rowNum: 10,
          mtype: 'POST',
          loadonce: true,
          rowList: [10, 20, 30],
          pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
          viewrecords: true,
          sortorder: 'desc',
          caption: "List Employee Details",
          loadComplete: function (result) {
          debugger;
          var i = 0;
          alert(result);
          },
          loadError: function (xhr) {
          // debugger;
          alert("The Status code:" + xhr.status + " Message:" + xhr.statusText); //Getting reponse 200 ok
          }           
       });    
    });
</script>
```

//and i am calling the function from default page. Here is my c# code.
//i am not using val but i need example with parameter passing.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string getData(int val)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

    return JsonParser.getJSONString(table);
}
```

I am getting error. Any body help me please? i am using jqgrid first time, and saw many examples and trying to do the same but not getting the result in the grid.

Comment: Can you include the error you are getting?

Comment: `I am getting error`. What error ?

Comment: Also add `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]`

Comment: I am getting status code=200

Comment: Could you use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to make HTTP trace of communication between jqGrid and the server. Could you append your question (click "edit" link under the text of the question) with the exact server response (at least one row of the data)?

Comment: i am seeing this in fiddler.  GET /Default.aspx?getData&_search=false&nd=1449665397174&rows=10&page=1&sidx=&sord=desc

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `WebMethod static` because `PageMethods` are always `static`.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string getData(int val)
{
 //your code.
}
```

Also you need to pass the paramter as `data` in ajax call.

```
data : JSON.stringify({ val : 2}),
```